# Reassign Task in Outlook does not work

Tags: sharepoint-server, task-list

I have any issue with using **Reassign Task** option when using outlook.
I need this functionality so users can delegate the task to another user when they receive the task email.
[image].
Its working if I send the task from our SharePoint Dev standalone box.

Kind Regards

Comment: Do you use 2010 approval workflow in SharePoint Server? Whether the task not to be assigned after specifying another user?

Comment: @Julie_MSFT that's correct I am using 2010 Approval workflow. None of the buttons are clickable when I tried in outlook. However in Dev environment everything's works fine.

Comment: What's the version of outlook? Do other users occur the same issue when thry open the task form in outlook?Do all task forms stop working?Try to clear the outlook cache to check the result.